# Google Maps API - Map.data scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am trying to add a GeoJSON layer to Google Maps (v3) by doing the following:

```
imageActive = {
    url: "images/target_red.png",
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 11),
} // ACTIVE marker image

jQuery.getJSON('home/gcpts/geojson.php', function(data){
    points = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
    console.log(points); //this works
});

map.data.setStyle({
  clickable: true,
  draggable: false,
});

map.data.addListener('click', function(event){
  setActiveImage(event);
})

function setActiveImage(event){
  for(var i = 0;i<points.length;i++){ //can't read "length" of undefined
    points[i].revertStyles();
  }
  map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
    icon: imageActive,
  });
}
```

However when I try to iterate through the "points" variable, I can't seem to "see" it. I mainly get undefined, or if I try to call the length of points (points.length), then it doesn't exist.

If I console.log(points) within the jQuery function, then I can see all of the features within the variable. If I place it on the outside, then I can't see it. Is there something I am missing about the scope?

It's my hope that I can set a "click" event and use event.feature to overrideStyle. Then when a different feature is clicked, then the style is removed from the other geoJson features and overrides the newly clicked feature.

It seems that this should work fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to iterate through the features.

Thanks!

(Also, I am using jQuery in "No conflict" mode...)

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to iterate through `points`.  Did you post enough code to see the problem?

Comment: @gilly3: Thanks for looking. Right now, I'm mainly concerned with "seeing" or calling up points from outside the jQuery function. I can add more js if necessary though. I just figured I might be handling map.data incorrectly and couldn't find the reason in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your variables are globally scoped because you aren't using the `var` keyword.  It seems likely that some other script is looking for a `points` variable and overwrites yours.  Assuming your code is already wrapped up in some kind of function (such as a jQuery `ready` handler), you may solve your problem by just using `var`.  I'd add this line of code before you call `getJSON()`:

```
var points = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer noted you need to ensure your "points" variable is scoped appropriately, but a better answer is that you don't need that variable at all:  Since you are using map.data you can just use that directly to access your features, using something like:

```
map.data.foreEch(function(feature) {console.log(feature);})
```

Note of course your "map" variable must be appropriately scoped.

Additionally, you also don't need to use jQuery -- you can just load the data using `map.data.loadGeoJson(theUrl)` which will do the ajax for you